# How to detect collisions between an eraser-tool boundary and a line generated by a Path?

Tags: android, graphics, collision-detection, android-canvas

I used a method where my eraser point has a bounds and what I did was loop through the array of line paths until one of those points in the path is withing the eraser bounds. Say that my eraser had a width and height of 20 pixels. If any points belonging to a path is within this region, it erases the Path.

However, this does not have 100% collision detection because there are gaps between a touch-generated path. When the user draws a path with their finger too fast, the app only records a small number of touch points with huge gaps in between. The eraser does not intersect the points on these Paths because of the gap.

Comment: Can't you interpolate between the eraser points (thick Bresenham segment) to restore continuity ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how Bresenham segment works but I did implement an eraser algorithm similar to that and it works but it is very slow. What it does is calculate lines between every point in the Path. Then it calculates line in the eraser's Path. Then all you need to do is check if the two lines intersect. However, this is computationally expensive and the lag is extremely noticeable. It is serviceable in a small signature-signing type app where there is a small amount of drawing from the user. But a full canvas can not handle this algorithm.

Comment: What is the processor clock speed ?